# Using Modals within Html Control-Labels in Bootstrap under ASP.NET.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to incorporate a modal for a user creation menu that has 15 mandatory
sign up boxes that are displayed from the model to the UI using their model properties through the

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

command. I want to add a mouse over modal to the fields so the user knows the field is mandatory to fill out before missing the field and getting the validation errors if the boxes are left empty. I want to use something like this but I don't know how to incorporate it into the @html label assignment.

```
            <a href="#" title="Address2" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" data-content="This Field is required">address2</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the relevant data attributes needed to enable popover. The second parameter of `LabelFor` helper method accepts an annonymous object for the html attributes. Make sure you pass the data attributes there.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", 
                                              data_toggle = "popover", 
                                              data_placement = "left", 
                                              data_trigger = "hover", 
                                              title = "Address2 is mandatory" })
```

One thing to remember is, to build the markup for data attribute, you need to replace `-` with `_` when passing the htmlAttributes to the helper method, that means, to get the output `"data-toggle"`, you should pass `"data_toggle"`

Also make sure that you have enabled the popover functionality by calling the `popover()` method on the element(s)

```
$(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

Comment: OK, Thanks so much for the tip. Can you explain a little more about the  - hyphen vs. the _ underscore thing in more detail if that's ok. This is shocking I never read about this in the literature and I've been reading about this for a while now. I'll try your suggestion in a few hours when I get home and give the props for a great answer if it works. Thanks so much !!!!!

Comment: Hi Shyju, Thanks for the response. I added the code above your last answer. It's not throwing any errors but the popover isn't working but the form is working fine. Just wondering what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you include the relevant bootstrap js files needed ? Also did you call the popover method on the jquery selectors ? I just tried the answer I posted on a page and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();doesn't the following make popovers work for all instances on the page.

Comment: Sorry I'm having problems editing my reply. But I'm very close to getting this right. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes.`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` will enable the popover behaviour on any element which has a data attribute` data-toggle` with value `popover`. You can change the value to `myCustom` if you do not like the above one. Make sure you update your label also to render `myCustom` as the `data-toggle` attribute value. This code should work fine. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4p0jIF) is a working sample

Comment: Shyju I'm very close now. I noticed you had @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer) field in your model. Is this necessary to make this work cause I don't have that type of field in my model. Other than that everything looks the same. When I mouse over the field nothing happens

Comment: Thanks so much for the sage advice Shyju it works perfectly with your code. I just had a bad reference to my base CSS file library. After I changed that it now works perfectly. Thank you so much for all your help great job !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, htmlAttributes: new {@class ="control-label col-md-2",
        data_toogle= "popover",
        data_placement = "right",
        data_trigger = "hover",
        title = "Address2 is mandatory"
        })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address2)

         </div>
     </div>
```

The above code is just displaying the control-label but it doesn't have the popover functionality. The script is the first script after the body and is exactly the way that was instructed.